# How to create model like firebase structure using RealmSwift in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, realm

I have been trying to create model like firebase database structure. I can able to create normal string, bool and int value but not able to do array and dictionary.

Here is my firebase structure screenshot:

[image]

Here i am trying to add **groupMembers** and **to** in model like firebase structure.

Here is my Model i tried to create with array and dictionary:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class RealmMessages: Object {

@objc dynamic var messageText : String?
@objc dynamic var sender: String?
let chatCreatedDateTimee = List<timeStampValue>()
@objc dynamic var chatId: String?
@objc dynamic var from: String?
@objc dynamic var groupMemberss : [String: String]!
let groupMemebersCount = RealmOptional<Int>()
@objc dynamic var task: Bool = false
@objc dynamic var to: Array = [String]()


}

class timeStampValue: Object {

  let timestamp = RealmOptional<Int>()

}
```

Here is my contoller code: Trying to add value into realm database.

```
var dic : [String : String] = [:]
var cont = ["one", "two", "three"]

var oneVal = ["909090": "SELF", "808080": "Other"]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let realm = try! Realm()

    print("realm location:::\(String(describing: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL))")


    let myMessage = RealmMessages()

    myMessage.messageText = "Diva"
    myMessage.sender = "yIvq1mQxjfZpjs1ybRTTlDOmUKV2"

    let timevalue = timeStampValue()
    timevalue.timestamp.value = 123123131

    myMessage.chatId = "+918000080000"
    myMessage.from = "+918000080000"

    myMessage.groupMemberss = oneVal
    myMessage.to = cont

    try! realm.write {

        realm.add(myMessage)
    }

 }
```

How to get **groupMemberss** and **to** structure in realm database like firebase. And how to create array and dictionary in realm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of solutions but here's two.

Assuming the data has been read in and the data from the groupMembers snapshot is sitting in a dictionary var that looks like this

```
let groupMembersDict = [
    "919": "participant",
    "111": "observer",
    "222": "participant"
]
```

To store that in Realm, you can work with primitives and store each key and value in a separate List (think: Array) or you can leverage a managed Realm object and store those in a List.

If you want to keep the data within an object; here's what it would look like.

```
class GroupData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var num = ""
    @objc dynamic var type = ""

    convenience init(withNum: String, andType: String) {
        self.init()
        self.num = withNum
        self.type = andType
    }
}
```

Here's the main object showing both options; either option 1: store the key value pairs in two arrays, or option 2: use the above GroupData object to store the key value pairs together

```
class Messages: Object {
    @objc dynamic var messageText = ""

    //option 1: two lists of primative strings that can be accessed like an array.
    // downside is managing two lists
    let groupNum = List<String>()
    let groupType = List<String>()

    //option 2: a list of members using another Realm object
    let groupNumType = List<GroupData>()
}
```

And some code to create two messages, one of each type

```
let msg0 = Messages()
msg0.messageText = "My message"
for member in groupMembersDict {
    msg0.groupNum.append( member.key )
    msg0.groupType.append( member.value )
}

let msg1 = Messages()
msg1.messageText = "This message"
for member in groupMembersDict {
    let aGroup = GroupData(withNum: member.key, andType: member.value)
    msg1.groupNumType.append(aGroup)
}
```

store them in realm

```
realm.add(msg0)
realm.add(msg1)
```

read them both in an display the message from option 2. Option 1 would be just iterating over the arrays to print the group data

```
let messageResults = realm.objects(Messages.self)

for msg in messageResults {
    print(msg.messageText)
    for group in msg.groupNumType {
        print(group.num, group.type)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that all managed properties must be primitives: NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber or List, Results, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject like the GroupData shown above.

Comment: Sry for late response.. thanks for answering. Will get back to you asap..